# Authentication with Azure AD, Spring Gateway, and multiple microservices

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I've been trying to figure this out for weeks and am stumped.

We are trying to migrate to SSO and I'm having some issues when the gateway sends the token to the downstream service. Authentication works fine in the gateway, and I am able to correctly view the authenticated user in the Spring Context.

I am using Spring Boot 2.2.0.

When the request hits downstream, I am getting the error

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Signed JWT rejected: Invalid signature
com.nimbusds.jose.proc.BadJWSException: Signed JWT rejected: Invalid signature
    at com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor.<clinit>(DefaultJWTProcessor.java:103)
    at com.microsoft.azure.spring.autoconfigure.aad.UserPrincipalManager.getAadJwtTokenValidator(UserPrincipalManager.java:94)
    at com.microsoft.azure.spring.autoconfigure.aad.UserPrincipalManager.buildUserPrincipal(UserPrincipalManager.java:85)
    at com.microsoft.azure.spring.autoconfigure.aad.AADAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(AADAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
```

Before I start getting into what I've learned so far through debugging, let me show you all what configurations I have in my applications:

## **Spring Gateway:**

`Application.properties`

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.redirect-uri={baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.scope=User.read
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.client-id=<<<My client ID>>>
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.client-secret=<<<My secret>>>
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.azure.issuer-uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/<<<Tenant id>>>/v2.0

azure.activedirectory.tenant-id=<<<Tenant id>>>
azure.activedirectory.active-directory-groups=Bench,Internal Projects

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=<<<App ID>>>
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=<<<App URI>>>
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=<<<Path>>>
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0]=RewritePath=<<<Rewrit Path>>>
spring.cloud.gateway.default-filters[0]=TokenRelay
```

`SecurityConfig`

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/eureka/**").hasAnyAuthority("SUPER_ADMIN")
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login();
        return http.build();
```

`Dependencies:`

```
dependencies {
    implementation "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.7.0"
    implementation "jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.2"
    implementation "org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.2"
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client"
    compile "com.microsoft.azure:azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter:2.2.2"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-security"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul-all"
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config"
    implementation "redis.clients:jedis:3.1.0"
```

With this configuration, the Spring Context is getting set in the gateway, the path hits the correct API and Endpoint, and passes an access_token downstream to my service

## **Now, for my downstream API:**

`Application.properties`

```
azure.activedirectory.client-id=<<<ID>>>
azure.activedirectory.client-secret=<<<Secret>>>
```

`SecurityConfig`

```
    @Autowired
    private AADAuthenticationFilter aadAuthFilter;

            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http
                        .csrf()
                        .disable()
                        .sessionManagement()
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                        .and()
                        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
                        .and()
                        .addFilterBefore(aadAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                        .exceptionHandling()
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(globalAuthEntryPoint);
            }
```

There's my setup. I have also tried by adding this to my application.properties:
`spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys` 
(I have also tried the v2.0 endpoint)

And when I do, I get this error:

```
Thu Jan 23 15:40:36 EST 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Signed JWT rejected: Invalid signature
com.nimbusds.jose.proc.BadJWSException: Signed JWT rejected: Invalid signature
    at com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor.<clinit>(DefaultJWTProcessor.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder$JwkSetUriJwtDecoderBuilder.processor(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:283)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder$JwkSetUriJwtDecoderBuilder.build(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:298)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.servlet.OAuth2ResourceServerJwtConfiguration$JwtDecoderConfiguration.jwtDecoderByJwkKeySetUri(OAuth2ResourceServerJwtConfiguration.java:68)
```

From what I understand, the downstream service is supposed to call Microsoft Graph to get the user information/authorities and set those in the Spring Context. It looks like it fails in the filter right before it does so.

Can anyone help me figure this Azure stuff out?

Comment: Were you able to solve this yet? I am having a similar issue.

Comment: Any solution yet? We have the same issue.